expo export --platform web registerRootComponent
I am trying build react native using expo and metro bundler using the below command
expo export --platform web
I am getting this below error

Starting Metro Bundler
Static rendering is enabled. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/static-rendering/
Web C:\Users\user1\git\app1\node_modules\expo/AppEntry.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  0.0% (1/1)
λ C:\Users\user1\git\app1\node_modules\expo-router\node/render.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  0.0% (0/1)Error: Unable to resolve module ../../App from C:\Users\user1\git\app1\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:

None of these files exist:
  * App(.web.js|.js|.web.jsx|.jsx|.web.json|.json|.web.ts|.ts|.web.tsx|.tsx)
  * App\index(.web.js|.js|.web.jsx|.jsx|.web.json|.json|.web.ts|.ts|.web.tsx|.tsx)
  1 | import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
  2 |
> 3 | import App from '../../App';
    |                  ^
  4 |
  5 | registerRootComponent(App);
  6 |
Error: Unable to resolve module ../../App from C:\Users\user1\git\app1\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:

how do I solve this issue ?
